# Get count of all items in a list that have one of the properties in another list

Tags: c#, linq

I am wondering if/how I can do the following thing using LINQ: I have a list of objects with some properties and another list of different distinct values corresponding to a certain property.

Example:

```
A = [{id=1, property=1}, {id=2, property=1}, {id=3, property=2}]
B = [1, 2]
```

Is there a way of achieving the following thing (obtaining the counts list) using only LINQ?

```
var counts = new List<int>();
foreach (var b in B)
{
    counts.Add(A.Where(a => a.property == b).Count();
}
```

Sample code:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public MyObject(int id, int prop)
    {
        Id = id;
        Property = prop;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Property { get; set; }

    public void test()
    {
        var A = new List<MyObject>
        {
            new MyObject(1, 1), new MyObject(2, 1), new MyObject(3, 2)
        };
        var B = new List<int>{1, 2};

        // LINQ magic

        // 2 objects with property 1
        // 1 object with property 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can just loop through the values and, for each one, get the count of items that have `Property == value`.

In the sample below, I'm selecting an anonymous type that contains the `Value` and the `Count` of each item that has `Property == value`:

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Property { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var allData = new List<Data>
        {
            new Data {Id = 1, Property = 1},
            new Data {Id = 2, Property = 1},
            new Data {Id = 3, Property = 2},
        };

        var values = new[] {1, 2};

        var results = values.Select(value => 
            new {Value = value, Count = allData.Count(item => item.Property == value)});

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{result.Count} objects with Property {result.Value}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use select operators to only select the specific properties you want to compare, and then use intersect and count to get the count. Example:

```
var listOfObjects = new List<PocoClass>()
{
    new PocoClass(){Id=1,Property=3},
    new PocoClass(){Id=2,Property=2}
};

var intArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

var count = listOfObjects.Select(o => o.Property).Intersect(intArray).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Count` method with a predicate:

```
var A = new[] {new {id = 1, property = 1}, new {id = 2, property = 1}, new {id = 3, property = 2}};
var B = new[] {1, 2};

var count = B.Count(b => A.Any(a => a.property == b));
```

Code above will check every member in `B` and if at least one member in `A` have a `property` with that value it will be counted

Comment: I think the original poster wanted a list of counts in A for each B. This solution will not supply that. It will give a count of items in B that have items in A.

Comment: @ChiralMichael Maybe I misunderstood question, but I think we should not guess what OP wants. He/she will left a comment or/and accept some answer.

Answer (score 0):

convert  B to List and run ForEach on it

```
B.OfType<int>().ToList().ForEach(m=>{ 
      counts.Add(A.Where(a => a.property == m).Count();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the gist of what you need. I'm typing this without a c# compiler, so hopefully this doesn't have errors.

```
var results = 
    from a in A
    join b in B on a.property equals b
    group a by a.property into g
    select new { Property = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }
```